# observable collection not changing combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an observable collection which is the item source to a combo box.  When I add a new item to the observable collection, it appears in the combobox.  However, when I update an existing item, it does not update the combo box.  What am I doing wrong?

xaml:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChildGroupOC}" DisplayMemberPath="childGroupName" />
```

observable collection property:

```
public ObservableCollection<ChildGroupBO> ChildGroupOC 
{
     get 
     { return childGroupOC;}
       set                 
     {
     childGroupOC = value;               
     }
}

public class ChildGroupBO: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int parentGroupId { get; set; }
    public int childGroupId { get; set; }
    public string childGroupName { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Does `ChildGroupBO` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: I updated the question to show the class.

Comment: That may satisfy the interface but you are not raising the changed event in the properties.

Comment: By updating you mean changing properties in a ChildGroupComboBoxBO?

Comment: Yes.  I am changing the filed childGroupName.

Comment: If you haven't seen it already: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of **ChildGroupComboBoxBO** not only has to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** but also call the event on changes:

```
OnPropertyChanged("parentGroupId");
```

**Example from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification):**

```
  public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private string name;
      // Declare the event
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public Person()
      {
      }

      public Person(string value)
      {
          this.name = value;
      }

      public string PersonName
      {
          get { return name; }
          set
          {
              name = value;
              // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
              OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");
          }
      }

      // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
      protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
      {
          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
          {
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Chrille and Crowcoder!  I developed a silverlight app a decade ago and I thought for sure that observable collections automatically binded values.  I must be mistaken.

Comment: ObservableCollection notify on collection changes (add, remove etc) but has no way of notify for changes of the items within the collection.